# Rspec TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Cipher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, zeus

I get an error when i'm trying to launch rspec :

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/factories_spec.rb.
Failure/Error:
  FactoryGirl.factories.map(&:name).each do |factory_name|
    describe "The #{factory_name} factory" do
      it 'is valid' do
        build(factory_name).should be_valid
      end
    end
  end

NameError:
  uninitialized constant FactoryGirl
# ./spec/factories_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::VERSION
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.so: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_LIBRARY_VERSION
```

and

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/helpers/date_helper_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

TypeError:
  superclass mismatch for class Cipher
# /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support.rb:24:in `require'
```

Please comment if you need more informations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the former error. You probably are using some modern version of FactoryGirl, and now it calls FactoryBot and uses `FactoryBot` constant. So use `FactoryBot` instead of  `FactoryGirl`

About the latter one. Maybe you have your `Cipher` class defined multiple times in multiple places and that's why you're getting this error. Or maybe you're trying to call it different than `OpenSSL::Cipher`. Any details about `Cipher` class could clarify the situation